# How to avoid covariate shift in python and distribute classes in each train and test phase?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, training

We all know that with the use of sklearn package from python, we can create X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test via this code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
```

I want to make sure that each training and testing phase of a multi-class data set, have 66.33/33.33 percent of each class values so the prediction and accuracy would get better. All i want is 66.33 percent of class A in training set and 33.33 percent of Class A in test set. And, so on for other classes, like B, C, D and etc. in a given multi-class data set.

Is the code provided enough to achieve this or should i write extra code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, stratify=y)` assuming that `y` contains your class labels. Alternatively, you can call `StratifiedShuffleSplit` directly.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, that it doesn't let me vote your answer. ./